# Why does it work to compare string values of invalid numbers?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, comparison, string-comparison

I was playing around with comparing version codes in JS and found that these types of comparisons work consistently and I have no idea why:

```
"3.4.06" < "3.4.02"   (false)
"3.3.01" < "3.4.02"   (true)
"3.3.01" > "3.4.02"   (false)
"3.5.2"  < "3.4.1"    (false)
"3.5.2"  > "3.4.0015" (true)
```

These are obviously not valid numbers in javascript, but somehow the JS engine is comparing the string values in a way that makes things work. Can anybody give some insight into how the JS engine is doing this? I'm running on V8.

Comment: https://javascript.info/comparison
Javascript compares strings letter by letter.
And as you might know, a char is basically a number in memory.

Comment: It just does lexicographical check character by character. `3` is before `4`, so `"3" < "4"` succeeds. However, that means that `"4" < "30"` is `false` since `4` comes after than `3`

Comment: lexical vs numerical. Stings are compared lexically. So `"100" < "9"`, because "1" comes before "9" and "100" isn't considered one whole entity. Numerical would compare the value of the entire number, where `100 > 9`

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea about the lexical comparison. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Because JavaScript is comparing every char in order. Let's say `"10" > "2"`, it will return `false`, because JS are comparing  `"1">"2"` first then it will result in `false`